# panda extract() operator return NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I need to extract specific values from data in a column on panda data frame and group another columns base on extracted values.
the pattern that I need is U1 ,U2 ,U3 ,... U9.

first of all I found the values on data with `match`:

```
filtered = df[df['column1'].str.match(r'(U\s*\d)') == True]
print(filtered['column1'])
```

The out put is like this:

```
9370       U 1 / U 2; Gleisdreieck, barrierefreier Ausbau
9371                           U 1 / U 3; Tunnelsanierung
9372     U 1 / U 6; Hallesches Tor; barrierefreier Ausbau
9373     U 1 / U 8; Kottbusser Tor, barrierefreier Ausbau
9374     U 1 / U 9; Kurfürstendamm, barrierefreier Ausbau
                               ...                       
34032               U9, Hansaplatz: barrierefreier Ausbau
34033            U9, Nauener Platz: barrierefreier Ausbau
34034             U9, Schloßstraße: barrierefreier Ausbau
34035               U9, Turmstraße: barrierefreier Ausbau
34250                                                 U25
```

Now, I need extract those U1 ,... U9 . I change my code like this:

```
extracted = df[df['column1'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)') == True]
```

but I got only NaN as value

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
        ... 
40815    NaN
40816    NaN
40817    NaN
40818    NaN
40819    NaN
```

Comment: just do `extracted = df['coloum1'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)')`. If you need to extract both U 1 and U 2 on the first row, use `extractall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `df['column1'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)') == True`, you're implicitly calling [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html).

> Get Equal to of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator eq)
> Returns : **DataFrame of bool**

You can simply use this to get the the first match :

```
extracted = df['column1'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)')
```

Or [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html?highlight=series%20findall#pandas.Series.str.findall) to get a list of all the matches :

```
extracted = df['column1'].str.findall(r'(U\s*\d)')
```

##### # Output :

```
      extract     findall
9370      U 1  [U 1, U 2]
9371      U 1  [U 1, U 3]
9372      U 1  [U 1, U 6]
9373      U 1  [U 1, U 8]
9374      U 1  [U 1, U 9]
...       ...         ...
34032      U9        [U9]
34033      U9        [U9]
34034      U9        [U9]
34035      U9        [U9]
34250      U2        [U2]

[11 rows x 2 columns]
```

##### # Edit:

Based on the comments, you can one of these solutions depending on your expectations :

```
donatation = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("zuwendungen-berlin.csv"))

# --- To create a Series with the extracted value (#Return: Series)
extracted = donatation['Zweck'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)', expand=False)
print(extracted)

# --- To create a new DataFrame with a single column containing (if possible) the extracted value (#Return: DataFrame)
extracted = donatation['Zweck'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)')
print(extracted)

# --- To create a new Column with the extracted value in the original dataframe (#Return: DataFrame)
extracted = donatation.assingn(New_Zweck= donatation['Zweck'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)', expand=False))
print(extracted['New_Zweck'])

# --- To filter the original dataframe without creating a column (#Return: DataFrame)
extracted = donatation.loc[donatation['Zweck'].str.contains(r'(U\s*\d)', na=False)]
print(extracted['Zweck'])

# --- To create a column with the extracted value and remove NaN values/rows (#Return: DataFrame)
donatation['New_Zweck'] = donatation['Zweck'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)')
extracted = donatation.loc[donatation['New_Zweck'].notna()]
print(extracted['New_Zweck'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I got again NaN as result.

Comment: Can you show the code used ?

Comment: my complete code is this: 
```donatation = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("zuwendungen-berlin.csv"))``` 
```extracted = donatation[donatation['Zweck'].str.extract(r'(U\s*\d)')]``` 

```print(extracted['Zweck'])```

```donatation``` is my df and ```Zweck``` is column that I should extract data from it

Comment: I'm not sure what's your expected output but I made and edit and you can check it out.

Comment: `donation[(condition)]` is a filtering that will return a DataFrame or Series that matches the `condition`. Try copy and paste exactly what @abokey posted without `donation[]`.